# Displaying date format SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I try to insert into tableA with

```
insert into tableA 
values (convert(date, '12-1-2012', 105))
```

then I try to

```
select * from tableA
```

it always shows the dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format

But when I use

```
select CONVERT(varchar, thedate, 105) from tableA
```

then it shows `dd-mm-yyyy`

Can I make even `select *` always shows the `dd-mm-yyyy` format?

Like changing the default display of date format?

Comment: probably, but it'd be part of changing the date/format settings in your OS, therefore would change ALL date/time outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to make a view, and set one of the fields in the view as:

```
CONVERT(varchar,thedate,105) AS thedate
```

and reference your VIEW in your select statement instead of your TABLE name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help:

[How to change Date Format after installing SQL server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2009/11/13/how-to-change-date-format-after-installing-sql-server/)